# how to replace div using jquery and kendo ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

i'm doing some tests, to do that i took a template on the kendo ui' page.
i clean it a bit to get what i want and right now, i have two div header in my html page.
i remove one at the load of the page and when i click on a button, i just want to remove the current header et set another one instead.
i've tried plenty of things but nothing seems to work correctly using jquery

here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<!-- 
    Contenu des pages chargées par le paneau left
-->
<body>
    <div data-role="view" id="drawer-home" data-layout="drawer-layout" data-title="Inbox"                                

    <p>recherche </p>
    </div>

    <div data-role="view" id="drawer-starred" data-layout="drawer-layout" data-title="Starred Items">
        <p>recherche </p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="view" id="drawer-drafts" data-layout="drawer-layout" data-title="Drafts">
        <p>recherche </p>
    </div>
<div data-role="drawer" id="my-drawer" style="width: 270px" data-views="['/', 'drawer-home', 'drawer-starred', 'drawer-drafts']">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-type="group"
 <li>Menu
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#drawer-home" data-transition="none">m1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#drawer-starred" data-transition="none">m2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#drawer-drafts" data-transition="none">m3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <div class="Head" data-role="layout" data-id="drawer-layout">
    <header data-role="header">
        <div class="" data-role="navbar">
            <a data-role="button" data-rel="drawer" href="#my-drawer" data-icon="drawer-button" data-align="left"></a>
            <span id="compagnyName">Demo</span>
            <a data-role="button" onClick="changeHead()" data-icon="drawer-button" data-align="right"></a>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
     <div class="HeadSearching" data-role="layout" data-id="drawer-layout">
    <header data-role="header">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <a data-role="button" data-rel="drawer" href="#my-drawer" data-icon="drawer-button" data-align="left"></a>
            <input type="text" id="city" name="city" class="k-textbox" placeholder="Ville" data-align="center" />
            <select name="country" id="country" data-align="right">
                <option>France</option>
                <option>Angleterre</option>
                <option>Luxembourg</option>
                <option>Espagne</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
    <script>
    var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
    $('.HeadSearching').remove();
</script>
    <script>
    function changeHead()
    {
        alert('header replace');
        $('.head').replaceWith('.HeadSearching');
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

if someone could help me doing this correctly ..
thanks by advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

Function `replaceWith(newContent)` as argument use `HTML` string. [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

You can try something like:

```
$('.head').replaceWith($('.HeadSearching'));
```

For this situation maybe is better to use show/hide different `div`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me without the '.'

```
$('Head').replaceWith("HeadSearching");
```

Answer (score 0):

For class selectors, you need to respect case. You're trying to select the element with `$('.head')`, but the class name is `Head`.

I'd suggest you always use lower-case ids and classes for simplicity.

In your case,

```
$('.Head').replaceWith($('.HeadSearching'));
```

should work, however you're removing the 
element you're trying to replace `$('.Head')` with:

```
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
$('.HeadSearching').remove();
```

So if you want to replace the .Head element with the .HeadSearching element, you need to remove the second line that removes all .HeadSearching elements.

If you want to hide `.HeadSearching` initially, then you should use `$(".HeadSearching").hide()` instead, and when you want to replace it, you could simply do

```
$(".Head").hide() 
$(".HeadSearching").show()
```

and vice versa.